# Angular MyCtrl as instead of scope not working for me

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope

I've got a form with hundred of fields.
As part of a secondary controller I'm trying to avoid the $scope to bind the data to my view. The way I go is:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SequencesController', SequencesController) // main controller for the view
    .controller('AccordionCtrl', AccordionCtrl); // the one I'm targetting

AccordionCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
function AccordionCtrl($scope,$http) {
    this.foo = "bar";
}
```

I'm using this on my view but it's not working.

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionCtrl as acc">
           Acc : {{ acc.foo }}
</div>
```

Using $scope does work though. Any ideas?

---

Extra information:
The view is binded to a main controller that's called like that in app.js

```
.when('/sequences', {
            controller: 'SequencesController',
            templateUrl: 'app/Sequences/sequences.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
```

Comment: Posted code is fine, probably something else is affecting. Post more code.

Comment: Or even better, create a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: added more info up there, off to plunker to try and mimick it

Answer (score -2):

When you are trying to access to the object(controller) property: `{{ acc.foo }}`, which angular is doing behind is: $scope.acc.foo, because this is how angular works, you must define your variables inside the scope.

If you dont want to interfer in the showing variables, create two diferent objects inside the scope: $scope.viewVars and $scope.backVars and add them all properties you need separately.

Comment: Ok I was trying to avoid the scope. The reason is when I load this controller, it calls a json object with hundreds of elements and my watchers go up to 1500+

Comment: There's no need to create more objects; Underfrog's use of the controller-as syntax is fine and should be working as is. Probably there's an issue in the HTML or another one of the scripts.

Comment: @Underfrog using controllerAs won't change anything to the number of watchers you have and to the performance of your page.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I couldn't plunker it because it's quite a large project. I understand the code is correct and would be polluted from elsewhere. I've reduced the watchers considerable by using {{::foo}} where I used to have {{foo}}